# Which versions of Eclipse is compatible with which versions of java?

Tags: java, eclipse

Basically I want to do java programming on my windows system having Windows SP3. Which version of java and Eclipse do I need to download?

Does JDK 1.6 (universal supporter) support all Eclipse and Apache tomcat???

Comment: JDK 1.6 is no longer supported. Don't download it.

Comment: I recommend you using the latest stable version of both Eclipse (Luna) and Java (8).

Answer (score 0):

Just go with the latest JDK 1.8 and Eclipse Luna. JDK 1.6 is no longer supported, and 1.7 is pretty much dead as well. Java 8 is far more modern anyway with its new features (lambda expressions, JavaFX 8, new Date framework, etc) and you'll be more competent as a developer knowing those features.

Also, if you are interested in Apache Tomcat you can also check out [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) instead of Eclipse. I understand it is much easier to do servlet development on.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA is Excellent tool . It supports wide variety of differnet languages....so all of you can be try.